# MySQL with Persistent Volume Claim on Kubernetes

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I created a volume and a persistent volume claim. Then I create a MySQL with a map to this volume claim. But the MySQL container does not start because: "2019-11-15T15:08:57.611908Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting."
Nevertheless, this is a fresh volume just created into which I have not added anything. How come there is something in it. How to clean it?
Thanks for any suggestions.
C

Comment: The first thing I'd check is whether the volume mounted correctly. It might have mounted as a new directory under where it is supposed to be, like /data/data/, or maybe mounted somewhere else, and you're looking at data left over from a previous run.

Comment: you can also mount the PVC into a temporary pod (like a busybox pod) and check if the volume is actually empty.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Actually, found workaround solution: used the yaml for pod creation that is given here https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/
Then logged into the pod, went to the directory and indeed, there was a "lost+found" directory which I believe is automatically created by Kubernetes. Removed this directory and ensure it is empty. Then started my mysql again ... and it worked.